# Probability Generating Function of Compound Poisson Process

Tags: probability-theory, generating-functions, poisson-distribution

Let $(N_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a poisson process with intensity $\alpha > 0$. Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be iid real valued random variables that are independent of $N_t$. Let $Y_t = \sum^{N_t}_{k=1}X_k$, a compound poisson process. I am trying to derive the PGF of $Y_t$ in terms of the PGF of $X_t$ when $X_1$ has density: $\rho(n) = \dfrac{-p^n}{n\ln(1-p)}, n \in \mathbb N$

**Attempt:** Let the PGF of $Y_t$ be denoted by $\phi_{Y_t}$, then:
\begin{align*}
\phi_Y(s) &= E[s^{Y}]\\
&=\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}s^iP(Y_t = i)\\
&=\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \sum^{\infty}_{j=1}s^iP(Y_t = i \mid N_t=j)P(N_t=j)\\
&=\sum^{\infty}_{j=1} P(N_t=j) \sum^{\infty}_{i=1}   s^iP(Y_t = i \mid N_t=j)\\
&=\sum^{\infty}_{j=1} P(N_t=j) \sum^{\infty}_{i=1}   s^iP(X_1+\cdots+X_j=i)\\
&=\sum^{\infty}_{j=1} P(N_t=j) (\phi_x(s))^j\\
&=\phi_N(\phi_X(s))
\end{align*}
Thus, 
$$
\phi_Y(s)=e^{\alpha t(\phi_{X_1}(s)-1)}
$$

Now, I've worked out that $\phi_{X_1} = \frac{\ln(1-ps)}{\ln(1-p)}$, therefore:

$$
\phi_Y(s)=e^{\alpha t\left(\frac{\ln(1-ps)}{\ln(1-p)}-1\right)}
$$

Could anyone verify this result?

Comment: It looks OK so far.  If I'm not mistaken, this will end up being a negative binomial distribution. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm confused as to how to progress to the next step though. How do I expand the second term out? I think the final answer is $\phi_Y(s) = \phi_N(\phi(s))$..

Comment: At a quick glance I'm inclined to think it's probably correct.  Maybe I'll say more later${}\,\ldots\qquad{}$